# Passing JavaScript string to C++ in the QtQuick environment

Tags: javascript, c++, parameter-passing, qt-quick

What I've been attempting to do is to call a C++ function from javaScript, ive got that bit working, i can print hello world to the console this way, however when i try to pass a string to the function to save it to file it only saves a blank line to the file. There are no errors printed to the console and the program seems to run fine.
Heres my code so far:
cppfunctions.h

```
#ifndef CPPFUNCTIONS_H
#define CPPFUNCTIONS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



class CPPFunctions : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CPPFunctions(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE void writeToFile(std::ofstream &outputFile, int x);
    Q_INVOKABLE void save(char dataDump);
    Q_INVOKABLE void hello_world();

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // CPPFUNCTIONS_H
```

cppfunctions.cpp

```
#include "cppfunctions.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



CPPFunctions::CPPFunctions(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{}

void CPPFunctions::writeToFile(std::ofstream &outputFile, int x)
{
    outputFile << x << endl;
}

void CPPFunctions::save(char dataDump)
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("C:/Users/jorda/Desktop/meme.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    outputFile << dataDump << endl;
    outputFile.close();
}

void CPPFunctions::hello_world() {
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
}
```

main.js

```
function randomNumber(){
    var number = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)).toString()+(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)).toString();
    return number;
}

function testCPP() {
    cpp.hello_world();
}
function saveCPP(){
    var temp = "..................";
    console.log(temp, "temp")
    cpp.save(temp)
}
```

Could someone give me an example of how to do this properly please, with a little explanation of how it works if its not too much trouble.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Your save function only accepts one CHARacter at a time. Since you want to print a string, I would suggest using QString as the input parameter. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html. This is however propably not the cause of your problem.

Comment: I should say that thats not the issue here, the issue is that the data that js passes to the cpp function is seemingly empty, ive tried with string, and QString fills the console with errors none of which are helpful